# How to manage 404 errors loading directive templates in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an AngularJS directive the `templateUrl` parameter is defined dinamically.

```
'templates/' + content_id + '.html'
```

I don't want to establish rules to check if `content_id` value is valid and manage it as 404 errors, i.e. if the template doesn't exist (server return a 404 error when loading the template) load `template/404.html` instead.

How can I do that?

Edited: The current answers suggest to use a response error interceptor. In this case ¿how can I know that the response is to a loading of this template?

Comment: I suspect this would be better handled on the server-side.

Comment: Maybe, but I want to know how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to write response error interceptor. Something like this:

```
app.factory('template404Interceptor', function($injector) {
    return {
        responseError: function(response) {
            if (response.status === 404 && /\.html$/.test(response.config.url)) {
                response.config.url = '404.html';
                return $injector.get('$http')(response.config);
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
});

app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('template404Interceptor');
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/uCpnT5n0PkWO53PVQmvR?p=preview

Comment: Why add the same answer half an hour after @NLN's answer?

Comment: @NexusDuck When I added my answer NLN's one was not like it's looking now, it was solving totally different problem than OP asked. But now it's the same right, basically because it was updated based on my answer and mine demo :) Just check revision history.

Comment: I did suggest the use of `interceptors` beforehand. I thought `$location` service would actually redirect the user to 404 template while it didnt. I later updated the answer with a working demo(and removed $location part in answer). Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: As in the other response: This will intercept any 404 error in xhr ¿isn't it? So if I create, or use, other directive, in case that template doesn't exist it will call `templates/404.html`.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an `interceptor` to monitor all requests made with the `$http` service and intercept any response errors. If you get a status 404 for any request made, simply redirect the user to error page(`template/404.html` in your case).

```
.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function ($q) {
    return {
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            if(rejection.status === 404){
                // do something on error                   
             }

            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
         }
     };
});
```

You would need to push the interceptor to `$httpProvider` in your config function.

```
myApp.config( function ($httpProvider, $interpolateProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
});
```

Here's the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/461vOcQHgp2TOAY65lgh?p=preview)

Cheers!

Comment: This will intercept any 404 error in xhr ¿isn't it? So if I create, or use, other directive, in case that template doesn't exist it will call `templates/404.html`.

Comment: @francadaval: yes, this will intercept all response status in all xhr requests